# Why we cannot use delegate property in mutableStateListOf in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to know that why we cannot use delegate property in `mutableStateListOf`. When I am trying to add

```
val favourites by remember { mutableStateListOf<Int>() }
```

It gives me error

```
Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
```

Also I tried to imports

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

but it stills gives the same error. Is there any specific reason for this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should be asking is how do i use `mutableStateOf` with delegation because delagation is not part of any class by default.

MutableState delegation is implemented as

```
/**
 * Permits property delegation of `val`s using `by` for [State].
 *
 * @sample androidx.compose.runtime.samples.DelegatedReadOnlyStateSample
 */
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline operator fun <T> State<T>.getValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = value

/**
 * Permits property delegation of `var`s using `by` for [MutableState].
 *
 * @sample androidx.compose.runtime.samples.DelegatedStateSample
 */
@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline operator fun <T> MutableState<T>.setValue(thisObj: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
    this.value = value
}

/**
 * A mutable value holder where reads to the [value] property during the execution of a [Composable]
 * function, the current [RecomposeScope] will be subscribed to changes of that value. When the
 * [value] property is written to and changed, a recomposition of any subscribed [RecomposeScope]s
 * will be scheduled. If [value] is written to with the same value, no recompositions will be
 * scheduled.
 *
 * @see [State]
 * @see [mutableStateOf]
 */
@Stable
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
    operator fun component1(): T
    operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit
}
```

Functions you import with

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

are `getValue` and `setValue` functions in snippet above.

You can create delegation functions for classes as extension functions which require you to import them or as part of class as in examples below.

```
class CalculateDelegate {

    private var calculatedProperty = 0

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int {
        return calculatedProperty
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        calculatedProperty = value * 2
    }

}

/**
 * Delegate [CalculateDelegate] to this function
 */
fun delegateCalculationFunction() = CalculateDelegate()
```

If you create a instances using

```
var delegatedNum1 by CalculateDelegate()
var delegatedNum2 by delegateCalculationFunction()
```

And then if you change or call setValue as

```
delegatedNum1 = 4
delegatedNum2 = 3
```

if you print these delegateNum1, and delegateNum2 you will see that they are 8 and 6 because of overriding `setValue`

If you wish to force overriding setValue and getValue functions for a class you can use ReadWriteProperty as

```
public interface ReadWriteProperty<in T, V> : ReadOnlyProperty<T, V> {
    /**
     * Returns the value of the property for the given object.
     * @param thisRef the object for which the value is requested.
     * @param property the metadata for the property.
     * @return the property value.
     */
    public override operator fun getValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>): V

    /**
     * Sets the value of the property for the given object.
     * @param thisRef the object for which the value is requested.
     * @param property the metadata for the property.
     * @param value the value to set.
     */
    public operator fun setValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>, value: V)
}
```

Then you need to override `getValue` and `setValue` functions.

```
class CalculateDelegate: ReadWriteProperty<Any?, Int> {

    private var calculatedProperty = 0

    override operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int {
        return calculatedProperty
    }

    override operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        calculatedProperty = value * 2
    }
}
```